# how to share iterator values between pages which have same backing bean?

Tags: oracle-adf

i have a Department jspx that have a command button on it , which call the operation binding commit :

```
void submit () {
OperationBinding Commit = ADFUtils.findOperation("Commit");
Commit.execute();
}
```

and i have a Employee Fragment dragged as a region on Department jspx

and both jspx and fragment look at the same Backing bean .

and in the backing bean i have method that fill a comments iterator programmatically as follows :

```
public void fillComments () {
OperationBinding operation = ADFUtils.findOperation("CreateWithParams");
operation.getParamsMap().put("InitType", initType);
operation.getParamsMap().put("BpmCrOutputId", mil_out_id);
operation.getParamsMap().put("MileOutId", mil_out_id);
operation.getParamsMap().put("CommentText", newComment);
operation.getParamsMap().put("ReqId", requestId);
operation.getParamsMap().put("ReqType", reqType);
operation.getParamsMap().put("UserName", loggedUser);
operation.execute();
}
```

before  there was a button on Employee fragment  that call fillComments ,
if i pressed that button , then i pressed the sumbit button on the jspx 
it execute successfully and the data is inserted in the database .

but i want to remove that button and call fillComments inside the sumbit button :

```
void sumbit () {
fillComments () ;
OperationBinding Commit = ADFUtils.findOperation("Commit");
Commit.execute();
}
```

i've tried that , but it didn't insert the rows in the database ,

i've added the createWithParams action twice  in both Fragment and JSPX Bindings

Comment: can you add the code for submit button

Comment: Its already added

Comment: I mean the source code in the page .jspx file